# How do I get matplotlib to actually update to the latest version?

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, conda, legend

I'm trying to change the font color in the legend of a barplot by setting the [labelcolor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) parameter, and it looks like I'll need Matplotlib 3.3 or later to do so (currently I'm getting `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labelcolor'` when I try). I currently have 3.2.2 installed.

I tried running `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib` in both my base environment and a custom environment, and it just "updated" to 3.2.2 again. I'd prefer to avoid trying a pip install so I don't risk screwing up other packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

translates to the imperative

> *With the **conda-forge** channel prioritized, ensure that some version of the package `matplotlib` is installed in the current environment.*

In contrast, according to OP, we want the imperative statement

> *Ensure that at least version 3.3 of the `matplotlib` package is installed in the current environment.*

which translates to the command

```bash
conda install matplotlib[version='>=3.3']
```

This does not guarantee that Conda can satisfy this command (e.g., it could conflict with previous specifications), only that this is the literal translation.

#### Channel Specification

Note that including `-c conda-forge` will prioritize that channel, but does not explicit specify that Conda must use that channel to source the package. This is because Conda will also take into account the `channel_priority` configuration value, and will behave differently depending on whether `'strict'` or `'flexible'` is set.

However, Conda's MatchSpec is sufficiently expressive to explicitly demand a particular package is sourced from a given channel. For example, to demand that at least version 3.3 is installed from Conda Forge, would take the form

```bash
conda install conda-forge::matplotlib[version='>=3.3']
```